# The following code only works when H5 is "Base". Could someone explain why?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
INDEX((H210,H410,H610),MATCH(H5,{"Base","Final","Alternative"},0))
```

The following code only works (return `H210`) when `H5` is "`Base`". It gives me a `#Ref!` error when `H5` is "`Final`" or "`Alternative`".

Not sure if the parentheses around `H210,H410,H610` is valid. I want to do this because the cells beneath it would have `H211, H411, H611` and so on. I want to just drag the formulas.

Can I create an array with cell references? How do I do that.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative could be the `CHOOSE` function, which will still update the ranges to `H211, H411, H611`, etc. as the formula is dragged.

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(H5,{"Base","Final","Alternative"},0),H210,H410,H610)
```

Answer (score 2):

(H210,H410,H610) is not a valid range reference for INDEX. Try,

```
=INDEX(H:H, MATCH(H5, {"Base","Final","Alternative"}, 0)*200+10)
```

Comment: Do u meant =INDEX(H:H, MATCH(H5, {"Base","Final","Alternative"}  0)*200+10)? That totally worked! Thank you.